# Internet explorer div contentEditable prevent DOM element selection onclick

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to update the `innerHTML` of a `<div contentEditable=true>` programmaticaly (javascript).

Using Internet Explorer < 8 or in Quirks mode if the HTML contains `<span>` tags one cannot not click to set the caret position, or navigate from char to char using keyboard.
Instead the `<span>` is selected (onclick) and can be moved/resized, or the caret jumps to the beginning/end of the `<span>` (keyboard arrows).

Screenshot:

http://i54.tinypic.com/343p75y.png

Do you know how to prevent this kind of selection?
Note that with Internet Explorer 8 in standard mode (or any other browser) I don't have this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with any element that [has layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). Make sure that none of the CSS properties that trigger layout are applied to your span and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks Tim, indeed there's some `style="zoom:1"` which seems to trigger the hasLayout property.
The problem is that I do not set this _zoom_ style on spans myself ...

Comment: @Jerome: I'm afraid you're a bit stuck then: once `hasLayout` has been triggered on an element, I don't believe there's a way to remove it. Sorry.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm creating the `innerHTML` myself and do not set the `zoom`style, It seems to be added by IE automatically.
I've tried to set it to `normal` afterwards, it solves the `hasLayout` issue but seems to trigger other problems (my functions to deal with the caret position don't work correctly anymore)

Comment: @Jerome: Interesting. I've never heard of IE automatically adding the `zoom` property. Have you got some code or a test page I can see? Have you considered using DOM methods (`appendChild()` etc) rather than `innerHTML`?

Comment: I've tried to setup a simple test page and did not reproduced it. So I've drilled down in my code and found that the zoom style is added when I'm setting tooltips on some of my span nodes (using Dojo's dijit.Tooltip)
The issue is spotted :-) thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Once again, Tim saves the day, Thanks. "min-height:" was causing this issue for me